# Automatically continue with exported file

Tags: python, file

I am currently working on my first script. First I want to execute the Decrypyter program.

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Service Delivery Tools\DataCollector\Decrypter.lnk"],shell=True)
```

After that I want to use the decrypted files. Is there a way to automatically reference the exported files? I have the code below so far.

```
conn_str = (
r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
r'DBQ=example_data\Example.accdb;'
)
```

Comment: what is that Decrypyter program? what format are the decrypted files? where are the decrypted files? what do you want to do with this files? Please update your question and clarify

Comment: `.lnk` is just a shortcut, not an executable itself, you need the actual path -- to use a connection string you need a module like [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/)